# Using R to calculate the same as a formula in excel

Tags: php, r, excel, statistics

Nether R nor general statistics are my strong point. So, as part of a build for a client, they have requested that some graphs have binomial data plotted, and they have provided me with a few formula they use to get the results they're expecting.

These formula are in excel, since I'm using  a CentOS VPS, I have installed R to do it for me, but I have been unable to find the correct functions to use.

Currently installed, Latest R lab and the Binom Package, I'm using an Rscript to do the calculations and PHP and Pchart to generate the actual graphs.

The data to be plotted is 4 binomial curves, with the alpha's of 0.9995, 0.0005, 0.995 and 0.005 respectively, with n being the position on the X axis

in this case (with cell numbers replaced by sudo variables to make this an easier read):

```
start = 1
xaxis = 0 (increments)
p = 0.01
alpha = 0.005
B = 1.7
```

the excel formula:

```
n = start+ROUNDDOWN(xaxis*EXP(1)^B,0)
critB = CRITBINOM(n,p,alpha)
Low-adj = critB-(BINOMDIST(critB,n,p,TRUE)-alpha)/(BINOMDIST(critB,n,p,TRUE)-BINOMDIST(critB-1,n,p,TRUE))
Low Alert = IF(ISERROR(100*Low-adj/n)=TRUE,"",Low-adj/n)
```

the above should return nothing and should continue to do so, until xaxis = 14, where the expected result is: Low Alert = 0.000156

Is anyone able to help with writing an Rscript to handle this? I was using binom.confinit() but the client has now come back with the above, so i need to replace binom.confinit with a script that will achieve this.

Its worth noting that this is part of a website, rather than a one off hence the php / pchart and not gnumeric.

Comment: You should be able to do this with base R (including plotting) using: `dbinom`, `pbinom`, `qdinom`, etc. See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Binomial.html

Comment: Can't you use php stats built in binomial stats_dens_pmf_binomial ( $p , $n , $alpha) ?

Comment: ahh thats perhaps good for replacing CRITBINOM, though I have no idea what the differences in binoms are. all I know is that I need to be able to reproduce the above.

Do you know of anything in php that can replace BINOMDIST?

Comment: @Thomas Having looked at that, i'm not entirely sure how this maps inplace of the 2 excel functions above.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did a quick check of your Excel formula, and there is no result produced for "Low Alert" with your givens (p=0.01, alpha=0.005) until n=528.  Is there a mistake in the formula?  I would hate to code up an R function for you that was based on an incorrect formula.

Comment: @Dinre i completly missed a column... your result will be about right, n is first being passed through 

where p17 is the axis and $B3 = 1.7

=n+ROUNDDOWN(P17*EXP(1)^$B$3,0)

where it is above 1.

i will edit the question to reflect this, thank you, that was a very good spot.

Comment: @Dinre that should be edited now

Sorry about that, thanks for your time :) i'm completely stuck heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting exactly the answer the OP is reporting from the formula, so I instead wrote a series of direct replacement functions for the Excel equivalents and wrote a sample of how they could be used in R.  This is not the most efficient method for R, but it may be the most expedient method of the OP moving towards implementation.

**CRITBINOM**: This is essentially a counting function.  It takes the size of a binomial trial, the probability of a success, and an alpha value.  It returns the smallest sample size where the cumulative probability is greater than the given alpha value.

```
CRITBINOM <- function(.trials, .probability_s, .alpha){
    i <- 0
    while(sum(dbinom(0:i, .trials, .probability_s)) < .alpha){
        i <- i + 1
        print(i)
    }
    return(i)
}
```

**BINOMDIST**: In Excel, this is actually two functions with a boolean switch.  If the switch is TRUE, the function returns the left-tailed cumulative distribution value of a given number of binomial successes given a trial size and probability of success.  If the switch is false, the function returns the probability mass function (probability of an exact number of successes) given the same info.

```
BINOMDIST <- function(.number_s, .trials, .probability_s, .cumulative){
    if(.cumulative){
        return(sum(dbinom(0:.number_s, .trials, .probability_s)))
    }else{
        return(choose(.trials,.number_s)*.probability_s^.number_s*(1-.probability_s)^(.trials-.number_s))
    }
}
```

**ISERROR**: In this case, the function is really just checking to see if the result of the function is infinite (undefined).  I'm not going to replicate all of the Excel functionality for such a specific use.

```
ISERROR <- function(.value){
    return(is.infinite(.value))
}
```

**ROUNDDOWN**: This is one of those weird little Excel functions.  It rounds, but it only rounds down.  When this is the case, we aren't actually rounding as much as we are truncating a number by multiplying by 10^digits, removing any remainder, and then dividing by 10^digits.

```
ROUNDDOWN <- function(.number, .num_digits){
    num_digits <- as.integer(.num_digits)
    return(as.integer(.number*10^num_digits)/(10^num_digits))
}
```

**Example R code**: Now I'm going to show how all of this could be used to replicate the OP's Excel task.  First, I'm going to define a vectorized function to calculate the 'n' values all at once.

```
n <- function(.start, .increments, .B){
    return(.start + ROUNDDOWN(.increments * exp(1)^.B, 0))
}
```

Next, I make a function to determine a single low alert value.  This is where most of the OP's work is incorporated.  The functions should look almost exactly the same.

```
generate_Low_Alert <- function(.n, .probability_s, .alpha){
    critB <- CRITBINOM(.n, .probability_s, .alpha)
    Low_adj <- critB-(BINOMDIST(critB, .n, .probability_s,TRUE)-.alpha)/(BINOMDIST(critB, .n, .probability_s,TRUE)-BINOMDIST(critB-1, .n, .probability_s,TRUE))
    if(ISERROR(100 * Low_adj / .n)){
        return("")
    }else{
        return(Low_adj/.n)
    }
}
```

Finally, I make a wrapper to feed the whole mess.

```
generate_data <- function(.B, .probability_s, .alpha, .start, .increments){
    Low_Alerts <- integer(length(.increments))
    n_values <- n(.start, .increments, .B)

    for(i in 1:length(n_values)){
        Low_Alerts[i] <- generate_Low_Alert(n_values[i], .probability_s, .alpha)
    }
    return(Low_Alerts)
}
```

I am essentially just looping through each of the 'n' values and generating an alert (either "" or the value of Low_adj/n).  All of this is stored in a single array and returned as the result of the function.

To use it all, I would call the wrapper function, like so:

```
generate_data(1.7, 0.01, 0.005, 1, 0:100)
```

Now, this is slightly different from the Excel approach, because we define the whole set of steps (0:100) at the beginning instead of one at a time.  Otherwise, this exactly replicates the Excel version of this that I built.

**Disclaimer**: I couldn't get the same results as the OP (saw alert at x_axis=97, instead of 14), but the mathematics of the Excel functions and these replacement functions should be exact.  Hopefully, you can take this work and adapt it to your needs.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :), I'll see what i can get. this is far better than anything I would of been able to get sorted, and looks like exactly what I need :)

apologies for the slightly screwy question, excel and general windows stuff isn't my strong point, I expect I missed something like a cell reference.

Thanks again :)